# Error on phone "unfortunately 'app name' has stopped" (OutOfMemoryError)

Tags: android

My newly made app is giving error on phone:

> "unfortunately 'app name' has stopped"

below is my logcat error

```
07-27 19:35:58.261 7466-7466/com.example.android.happybirthday E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.example.android.happybirthday, PID: 7466
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:683)
     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:513)
     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:889)
     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3436)
     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:133)
     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:102)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:972)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1030)
     at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:690)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:136)
     at com.example.android.happybirthday.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `OutOfMemoryError` seems obvious enough...

Comment: what is your image size and dimention? You are trying to load too big image in imageview.

Comment: You ran out of memory.  It could be you're just using a truly large bitmap, but most likely you're either storing way too much data or you have a memory leak.  I'd look at some heap profiles of your app and see where the memory is being used.

Comment: Can you provide more details ? Some code would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

try to put this into the application tag of your manifest:
`android:largeHeap="true"`

Comment: Don't do this.  Its a hack that will work on only a subset of devices, and won't fix your real problem.  It may not even fix your current problem.